# Import fixwidth text files with scriptella

Tags: scriptella

What is the best method to import a fixwidth file into a table with scriptella?

Textfile:

```
blabla bloblo ble    bli
```

Columnwidth:

```
(1,7) (8,14) (15,21) (22,24)
```

Table:

```
T_IMPORT (
  FIELD1 VARCHAR(8),
  FIELD2 VARCHAR(8),
  FIELD3 VARCHAR(8),
  FIELD4 VARCHAR(4)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <connection id="database" url="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mymemdb" user="SA" password=""/>
    <connection id="in" driver="text" url="${filePath}test_import.txt" />
    <query connection-id="in">
            <script connection-id="database">
                INSERT INTO T_IMPORT 
                VALUES (
                ?{column0.substring(0,7)},
                ?{column0.substring(8,14)},
                ?{column0.substring(15,21)},
                ?{column0.substring(22,24)});
        </script>
    </query>
</etl>
```